# How do I check if Perl code is safe if I dont know perl language?

Tags: perl

Perl looks very simple and small.

A friend wants me to run a simple perl code and I dont understand if that perl script will do more than what is supposed to do.

Could perl scripts work like backdoor? Probably yes then..

How would a non programmer look if that perl script is not capturing display information, recording keystrokes and other things?

Thank you

Comment: Is it some code you have access to, and if it is safe to open the file is it possible for you to paste the code?

Comment: I cant paste the code because google would probably store it and then my friend would notice that I am not trusting his code. :)

Comment: If you dont trust it and dont understand it, dont run it. I dont see why you can not post the code here, your explanations are not very convincing and all this seems a bit childish to me. Sorry.. but how exactly do you think we could help you?

Comment: Why do you keep calling this individual your friend?  He's given you code you're afraid to run.  You're afraid to post it because he might see your post.  This is a friend?  Post your code.  Otherwise, your question is unanswerable.  A Perl one-liner could delete your hard drive.

Comment: With a perl script, you can do a great many things. I think the question here is your relationship with your "friend". If he gives you code, and you don't trust it, you don't HAVE to use it. There is no way to answer a carte blanche question like that, perl can do a great many things, in fact, just about anything to your system.

Comment: How?  By showing it to someone who does know perl.

Comment: I must say, I disagree with closing this question. The OP has a problem, and admittedly a strange one, however he knows that he is going to have to deal with it on his own as he can't post it; I much prefer questions like "what are some vulnerable things in Perl" than "do this thing for me". I feel that I have answered with a clear and useful post too.

Comment: A last ditch effort to come up with a real answer; @lkl, would you be willing to post the script encoded in base64?  Your "friend" (I use the term loosely from what I've read here) couldn't search for it directly, and he'd have to be pretty far gone to search for the b64'ed version.  If so, use this: `perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64(qx{/bin/cat name_of_your_script});'` - which cats the script, encodes it in base 64, and prints it.  Without this, @Joel's post is a really good starting point, but it's impossible to enumerate *all* the bad things someone could do in a Perl script.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't understand the script, then you have no more guarantees than if you ran a plain binary executable. That is to say: you don't really have any guarantees.

Obviously, don't run the program as root (:

If you really need to run the script and you don't trust your friend, you could try running it inside a 'sandbox', such as a virtual OS, a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)'ed environment or a [jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail).
Here's [one more link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization) along those lines.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it. It would be good to know though but I guess the only way is that I need to learn how to programs and there is no fast way to do that. :(

Answer (score 4):

Since you suspect the script to be malicious you should probably **not run it**. If possible, as has been suggested, paste your code so that we can have a look.

Comment: I cant paste the code, he might search it on google and he would notice I dont trust it.

Comment: Why is it bad if your friend learns that you value your security? Be straight with your friend, tell her that you do not trust her code and you don't run unverified code because you value your security.

Answer (score 1):

With some notable exceptions, we can make a checklist that should ease some fears.

1. Post here or investigate the modules used (`use Some::Module`) most of these modules will exist on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org), the public repository of Perl modules. While this will be an open ended search, this will help you see if a logger or network connection is being used (`use strict; use warnings;` is ok).
2. Post here or make note of all `open` commands as these are the ones that can read/write to files or make other system connections.
3. Post here or investigate all `system` commands or even backticks "  `  " as Perl uses these to run programs on your computer.
4. Perl also has mechanisms to hide this kind of activity. For example the `tie` command lets these actions be hidden in variables and the `use overload` pragma lets them be hidden in functions or operators. (many of these need to be done inside a `package` environment (for lack of a better word) so make note of these). Finally the `eval` and `/e` or `/ee` regex flags are used to evaluate (read: do) code which is in some other form, perhaps stored in a variable, or created on the fly, hidden code may be "made alive" through this mechanism.
5. The glob operator "  *  " allows renaming of almost anything in Perl, so one might follow along if one sees for example `*something = \*STDOUT`. Note that this is the same symbol as the simple multiplication operator.

Again there are plenty more ways of doing malicious things in Perl, AND none of the above things are untoward or even uncommon in and of themselves, still perhaps this will give you a place to start.

Comment: You notably missed both `eval` and `s///ee` either of which can be used to execute code that could have been well hidden.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, True enough, added

Comment: joel, is it possible to send private messages here? if it is I might send the code and if you want to have a look at it in your free time. Sorry I cant post in public. Another question, when you say executable commands, do you mean clear things like "dir"  "cd" "program.exe" ?

Comment: it uses IO Socket INET modules but the script should access the internet working normally.

Comment: @lkl, sorry, there are no PMs, at least that I am aware of. As far as executable programs, or system calls (point 3), yes anything that you could type into a command line can be run from Perl. `cd` probably won't do anything useful, at least by itself as Perl system calls are independent of each other. You can investigate more using perl's documentation, officially at http://perldoc.perl.org or more easily accessible at http://p3rl.org

Answer (score 0):

It is really not possible to know if a script is malicious or not (even picture-files can contain malicious code!), but if you want to run it try running it in a virtual machine, a sandbox or even on http://codepad.org (just tell the author if you can break it, so he can fix it, or that is what the [author says](http://codepad.org/about)).

Comment: images with malicious code? I didnt know that.

Comment: There are known exploits that occur through tweaked image files.

Comment: @lkl: This is assuming you open it with a buggy image viewer. Of course just about everything is buggy...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask him to explain how it works, line by line? If he's actually your friend I can't imagine why he'd want you to run malicious code.

Comment: That is human nature, it is hard to know if a person is really a friend.

Comment: If you don't know someone well enough to call them a friend, and you don't trust them, then don't run it.